# Is there a way to change the color of the left pane that has the line numbers of Ace-Editor in React?

Tags: reactjs, ace-editor

I have already tried setting the background color using the style prop provided by AceEditor but that only works for the body. How can I change the background color of the left pane that has the line numbers to transparent too?

```
      <AceEditor
        mode="javascript"
        theme="dreamweaver"
        // onChange={onChange}
        style={{
          backgroundColor: "transparent",
          fontSize: "1.2rem",
          color: "white",
        }}
        name="UNIQUE_ID_OF_DIV"
        editorProps={{ $blockScrolling: true }}
        value={`function onLoad(editor) {
                  console.log("i've loaded");
              }
             `}
      />
```

Answer (score 1):

In a non-React-specific way, you could change the line number panel ("gutter") background with CSS like so

```css
.ace-tm .ace_gutter {
    background: #F8F8F8;
}
```